# Trying to select only one subset

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a sql code where I get only one subset.

```
rej_npa  npa     rej_nxx    nxx    from_Number    to_number

867      867        250     252        0000          0999
867      867        250     252        1000          1999
867      867        250     252        2000          2999
867      867        250     252        3000          3999
867      867        250     252        4000          4999
867      867        250     253        0000          0999
867      867        250     253        1000          1999
867      867        250     253        2000          2999
867      867        250     253        3000          3999
867      867        250     253        4000          4999
```

from this subset I am trying to get only one it can either be this

rej_npa   npa     rej_nxx    nxx    from_Number    to_number

```
867      867        250     252        0000          0999
867      867        250     252        1000          1999
867      867        250     252        2000          2999
867      867        250     252        3000          3999
867      867        250     252        4000          4999
```

or

this

```
   rej_npa   npa     rej_nxx    nxx    from_Number    to_number
    867      867        250     253        0000          0999
    867      867        250     253        1000          1999
    867      867        250     253        2000          2999
    867      867        250     253        3000          3999
    867      867        250     253        4000          4999
```

But I need only one subset from it
Please help on this

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t WHERE nxx = 252` comes to mind.

Comment: @Gordan this is just one of the example I have different subset like this where nxx is not 252 those different nxx's

Comment: And hence your question is not clear on what you really want to be doing.